# Sequelizejs - Then result issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm work with NodeJS and Sequelize. I have the following issue:

Read the Settings Table:

```
    Settings.findOne({where: {
        user_id: data
    }})
   .then(settings => {
    // Next request
   });
```

I need to save the `settings.device (Example)` outside of the `.then` block.
But if I do that like

```
var device;

Settings.findOne({where: {
      user_id: data
    }})
   .then(settings => {
      device = settings.device;
   });
```

It doesn't work.

Already the error output `undefined`

The output in `.then` result block with `console.log(settings.device);` works perfect.

Update

I need it like:

```
    var array = [];

    // Get Settings from table
    Settings.findOne({where: {
        user_id: data
    }})
    .then(settings => {

        // Get token from other Table
        Example.findOne({where: {
            user_id: data
        }})
        .then(example => {
            // push to array 
            array.push({
                "user_id" : data,
                "device":settings.device, // output: settings.device is undefined
                "token": example.token
            });

        });

    });

    // Send array to client
```

Comment: The sort answer is "Move the work inside the `.then` block".

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Does the variable device resolve to undefined? Does it throw an error? If you are using the device value after the code you provided, you should await the findOne query to finish and then perform any other operations

Comment: @Sidney Thanks for your answer. The problem is, I need to start in 'then' block the next 'example.findOne ... .then(exampleresult)' and after this I have to push the result to a JS Array. I can do that like your answer, but the result from settings > then is also not available in the next .then block from 'example.findOne' ...

Comment: If `example.findOne` is inside of the `then` block from `Settings.findOne`, you have access to the result of settings. If you post the rest of your code, I can write a longer answer that shows how to rewrite the code.

Comment: @DavDeveloper Your code is not showing us where you're using `device` and getting `undefined`. This issue is not actually Sequelize related. You're just dealing with multiple promises (a promise chain) and wanting to have multiple resolved values available in subsequent calls. You can do this by returning multiple things in each statement (as an array or object) or by defining variables at a higher scope and then re-assigning their value as you're attempting here. A much simpler way would be to use async/await.

Comment: @Sidney I have updated my post, I hope you understand, what I mean.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser Thanks for your answer! Do you have maybe a little example for a async/await block with sequelize?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question of how to handle multiple resolved values in a Promise chain. You can search for that and see lots of great examples on how to handle it. For example, you could return an array or object in each `then` handler, or re-assign values to higher-scoped variables (as you're doing with `settings`). I've used both methods heavily in the past, and the resulting code is obviously inelegant and not fun to write.

However, async/await is readily available in Node and simplifies your code quite a bit:

```
const array = [];

// Get settings.
const settings = await Settings.findOne({where: {
    user_id: data
}});

// Get token.
const example = await Example.findOne({where: {
    user_id: data
}});

array.push({
    user_id : data,
    device: settings.device,
    token: example.token
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize return the model object you can get value by [dataValue](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)

```
 console.log(settings.dataValues.device);
```

or if you want lean data

```
 Settings.findOne({where: {        
  user_id: data,
  raw:true,
    }})
   .then(settings => {
     device = settings.device;
     console.log(device);
   });
```